# How to display Kendo grip with dummy data on the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am very new to kendo and am still trying to learn it. I want to display my grid on the form but it is not displaying. the page only changes the color. All i want is the grid to appear on the form and then i will later bind the data from my model. but now i have created object array to pass the data to the form. Am not sure if i have to install something or add more reference.

here is what i have done so far,

**My View**

```
 <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h2 class="box-title">Reports</h2>
                </div>
                <br />
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div id="grid"> //my grid

                        </div>
                       </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

**Javascript**

```
 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function ()
        {
            //array objects which will add the data to the table
            var People = [{ firstName: "Enos", lastName: "Es" }, { firstName: "Ray", lastName: "Rs" },
                            { firstName: "Justice", lastName: "Js" }, { firstName: "RR", lastName: "ESW" },
                            { firstName: "Gop", lastName: "Gp" }, { firstName: "DS", lastName: "JN" },
                            { firstName: "Raven", lastName: "Rv" }, { firstName: "FD", lastName: "FDGH" },
                            { firstName: "Andrew", lastName: "Ar" }, { firstName: "DDD", lastName: "GFG" },
                            { firstName: "Shayne", lastName: "S" }, { firstName: "YYY", lastName: "GHFGH" },
                            { firstName: "Walter", lastName: "W" }, { firstName: "EEE", lastName: "LUIO" },
                            { firstName: "ZKZG", lastName: "RD" }, { firstName: "JJJ", lastName: "FGJHGH" }
              ]
            //creating my grid and defining the column headers
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                columns: [
                    { title: "First Name", field: firstName },
                    { title: "Last Name", field: lastName }],

                //now am specifying the data or binding the data to the datasource
                dataSource: {
                    data: People,
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                height: 400,
                scrollable: true,
                pagebale: true,
                sortable: {mode: "multiple"}
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

}

**Stylesheet**

```
   <link href="~/Content/Kendo/styles/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Kendo/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Kendo/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/console.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you see any console errors in your browser developer window?

Comment: I didn't check. i will have a look at it now

Comment: I went to console ad i got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: firstName is not defined. Can you please clarify for me?

Comment: Place `dataSource` attribute above the `columns` attributes

Comment: I have fixed the previous error and now am getting this error: kendoGrid is not a function. @vispan i have tried and it didn't work. please help

Comment: see if your script is loaded after `kendo.all.min.js` file. Basically the error says it doesnt understand the `kendoGrid `

Comment: It is loaded correctly, I will delete it and reload it again to see if i will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by rendering the javascript first. and it loads the grid

```
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

}